# LESS CSS & Symfony - Updating color schemes dynamically

Tags: php, css, symfony1, symfony-1.4, less

I'm working with the Symfony 1.4 and I'm running into a bit of a problem using the LESS CSS preprocessor.

Let's say that I have 2 Less files with color specific variables.  They are called `blue.less` and `red.less`.

Here they are:

**Blue.less**

```
@mainBorder: blue;
@pulldownBackground: blue;
```

**Red.less**

```
@mainBorder: red;
@pulldownBackground: red;
```

Now let's say that I have a **layout.less** file that will look something like this:

```
// Colored line under Nav
.main {
    border: 1px solid @mainBorder;
    .pullDown { background: @pullDownBackground; }
}
```

If I want to use one of the color variable files, I need to declare it at the top of the **layout.less** file like this:

```
@import 'red.less';
```

Since the `@import` statement has to reference a specific file, how would I be able to dynamically pass `blue.less` to the @import statement whenever I wanted to change the color scheme?

**Would there be a way to dynamically declare which of the color specific LESS files will be passed to that import statement with PHP and the Symfony framework?**

Or can this problem be solved without server-side code?

Comment: Have you considered generating the LESS file containing all of the necessary imports via PHP and then using `exec` to invoke the compilation?

Comment: I have not.  I'm fairly new to PHP and Symfony - the Less files are currently being processed through the sfLess Plugin:  http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfLESSPlugin.  It would be great if you could point me toward a tutorial that could get me started on what you are suggesting.  I'll look up the PHP exec function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Symphony, but this should get you going in the right direction regardless of framework.

First you want to create your LESS file:

```
<?php
$color_scheme = "red"; // we're simplifying here for now, but this could be set via $_POST variable

/*
    it would probably be a good idea to check if the file exists first before we import it.
    see function: file_exists()
*/

$contents = "
@import '$color_scheme.less';
@import 'main_styles.less';
@import 'other_stuff.less';
";

file_put_contents("path/to/styles.less");
?>
```

Now you have a LESS file that is ready to be processed, same as if you written it by hand, but with the color scheme being easily swappable.  If I were doing this with bare PHP, I would be using the `exec()` function to invoke commands that would be available via command line.  Here's an example for invoking SASS via `exec()` (I've never used LESS this way, so you'll have to fill in the blanks here).

```
<?php
exec("sass --compile path/to/sass:path/to/public/css");
?>
```

If your Symphony plugin does the compilation for you without the need to use the exec/command line, then you'll probably want to do that instead.