# Edit external CSS/SCSS with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I need to 'edit' a file that's already saved on my server, **example:**

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugin.scss">`

But not only that, I want to edit a certain specific line, in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) you can define variables in css, basically, I'd like to search inside this file with JAVASCRIPT for the string:

`'$increment:`

And if it's found, find out what line it is on and replace that whole line with:

`'$increment:10;`

Basically I want to generate a downloadable file for the user that's custom depending on what settings they choose via a html input field.

If there's a simpler/better explanation I'm all ears :)

Comment: The better, simpler approach is to *override* the external stylesheet with a local stylesheet or inline styles. Inline styles are easy to apply using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css). Editing external files is beyond the scope of JavaScript's abilities, though.

Comment: @Blazemonger, he would like to create a downloadable file, not a style applied to his website.

Comment: Possibly related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693981/less-css-symfony-updating-color-schemes-dynamically

Comment: What you are probably looking for is: https://github.com/mechio/takana the tool setups a bridge server then you add a js snippet to your page to allow the server to edit your css file. Then again, you will have to use sublimetext which is currently the only editor able to talk with the bridge server. Another alternative is using http://livejs.com

Answer (score 1):

The javascript you seem to be referring to (jQuery) is a client-side language so you're not going to be able to do anything on your server with it. A js solution that could do this may be written in nodejs but you may be better served using something like Python, Rails, or even PHP.

Comment: I never mentioned jquery?

Comment: You tagged it as javascript, jQuery, css, and SASS.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't mention jquery in my OP, but anyway, do you have a solution for PHP?